# how do i get value of data member from subclass?if i have codes like this

Tags: oop, dart

I'm still learning flutter/dart language tutorial.
This is my code. I create method that can return an object.How do i get data member from subclass via the method.

```
abstract class Shape{
  get area;
}
class Circle implements Shape{
  final radius; 
  Circle(this.radius);

   get area=>pi*pow(radius,2);
}

class Square implements Shape{
  final side;
  Square(this.side);
  get area=>pow(side,2);
}

Shape shapeFactory(String type){
  if(type=='circle') return Circle(2);
  if(type=='square') return Square(2);
  throw 'Can\'t create $type.';

}

void main() {
  var s=shapeFactory('square');
  print(s.area);
  print(s.side);
  var c= shapeFactory('circle');
  print(c.area);
  print(c.radius);
}
```

as u can see,i can get area value,but i can't get radius or side values from class circle or class square which is subclass of class shape

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? I don't know whether it's relevant to either Java or C# either but I can't be sure. Don't just tag with all the languages you can

Comment: that was a mistake,i was hoping to get more attention from many people.so i can get more answer,more information that maybe i don't know before.i'll make better question next time.

Comment: People don't like when someone draws their attention for something they have no interest in. If you want attention it's best to ensure to post proper questions where it's clear what the problem is (your question is fine btw).

Comment: I forgot that you still need to cast. I added `as T`.

Comment: oh i see,it works.Thanks a lot sir

Comment: I don't understand the `as T` (and can't see where `T` is declared)? Should it be changed in the answer below instead of the question?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to update my answer not your question :D - fixed - see my updated answrr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Shape` doesn't have these properties. You need to cast to the specific type first or make `shapeFactory` generic.

```
void main() {
  var s=shapeFactory('square') as Square;
  print(s.area);
  print(s.side);
  var c= shapeFactory('circle') as Circle;
  print(c.area);
  print(c.radius);
}
```

or

```
T shapeFactory<T extends Shape>(String type){
  if(type=='circle') return Circle(2) as T;
  if(type=='square') return Square(2) as T;
  throw 'Can\'t create $type.';
}

void main() {
  var s=shapeFactory<Square>('square');
  print(s.area);
  print(s.side);
  var c= shapeFactory<Circle>('circle');
  print(c.area);
  print(c.radius);
}
```

Comment: if i use this algorithm


T shapeFactory<T extends Shape>(String type){
  if(type=='circle') return Circle(2);
  if(type=='square') return Square(2);
  throw 'Can\'t create $type.';
}


what does 'T' mean??
is it representing the subclasses of shape class or what?

Comment: It is like a variable for a type (in contrary to a variable for a value). When you call `shapeFactory<Square>` `T shapeFactory<T extends Shape>(String type){` becomes `Square shapeFactory(String type){`

Comment: so i have to make another method with different name but have proper data type?
or can i do overriding ??

Comment: No, my answer after "or" shows how to do that. It parameterizes `shapeFactory` with a type parameter `T`. Nothing required in addition.

Comment: the first algorthm works perfectly but when i try the second algorithm. i found error message 

"The return type 'Circle' isn't a 'T', as defined by the method 'shapeFactory2'."

Comment: @Galihindra I can't reproduce your problem. Eiter please provide more information or create a new question with full details.